# Angular make translation global

Tags: javascript, angular, translate, angular-translate

I use **TranslateService** from **@ngx-translate** and every tutorial I found is pretty much the same.

The problem is.. I have in root AppComponent this:

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(["en", "fr"]);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');

    let browserLang = translate.getBrowserLang();
    translate.use(browserLang.match(/en|fr/) ? browserLang : 'en');
}
```

In header event which change language:

```
<select #langSelect (change)="translate.use(langSelect.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let lang of translate.getLangs()" [value]="lang" [selected]="lang === translate.currentLang">{{ lang }}</option>
</select>
```

and I want this to be global, the change event to propagate into my all modules, components etc. Is there a way to do that, or I must inject this service every place I use it?

Thanks.

Comment: did you manage it to solve this problem? I'm struggling with it as well

Comment: Yes. I use Observable with Subject and it works. Also a solution is ng2-redux. I will try to paste an example next week here.

Answer (score 1):

Either you need to wrap this in a module and include in every page or you cab separate out this component in a different controller altogether and render it as a part of header so that it gets rendered from the layout.

Comment: I have feeling must be something cleaner then your way. I will make research and come back with results. Thanks for your info!